# I am adding a css rule to elements when i click on them using javaScript, but the rule does not seem to be working

Tags: javascript, css

Here is my CSS. My goal was to add the `.show` rule whenever you clicked on a certain tab so that it would show the neccesary content but it does not work.

```
#tab-1-content, #tab-2-content, #tab-3-content {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

And this is my entire Javascript page. I put the `console.log` to see in the console if the `show` class was being added correctly and it seems like it is whenever I click on it, but it does not show the content like it should.

```
const tabItems = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-item');
const tabContentItems = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content-item');

// select tab content item
function selectItem(e) {
  removeBorder();
  removeShow();
  //Add border to current tab
  this.classList.add('tab-border');
  //Grab content item from DOM
  const tabContentItem = document.querySelector(`#${ this.id }-content`);
  //Add show class
  tabContentItem.classList.add('show');
  console.log(tabContentItem)
}

function removeBorder() {
 tabItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('tab-border'));

}

function removeShow() {
 tabContentItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('show'));
}

// Listen for tab click
tabItems.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', selectItem));
```

My Border variables work as intended, removing the border and adding it to the element I click on. I tried to just make a Netflix Landing Page clone as a bit of a project, here is the link to that website https://netflx.github.io/ .  I removed the footer and Replaced the images as my anti-virus would not let me access the site. I tried to do exactly what netflix does, by having the different sections pop up when you click on the different tab elements but it does not do that. It only works for the first tab but does not show the content for the other two tabs. Does anyone know what is going on and how I can fix it?

Comment: What does the DOM inspector say? Do you see the element getting the class or not? If it is, then something else is overwriting the style. You can see all this in the inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DOM structure is going:

`.container > #tab-1-content > .tab-{tabnumber}-content`

So your div with an id of `#tab-1-content` is always set to display none.

I think you've got your class and ID names mixed up. `#tab-1-content` is always set to `display: none` so only the first tab displays because `.show` is being applied to that outer div but when the inner divs are set, the outer div is still not showing.

[image]
.

Check out the image, the div IDs dont make sense. Remove the `#tab-1-content` from the outer div. Remove the `.tab-1-content-inner` class from the inner div and give it an ID of `#tab-1-content` and that should get you going.

[image]

Like so.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your HTML Syntax.

tab-2-content and tab-3-content are in the tab-1-content.

You should fix them like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="tab-1-content" class="tab-content-item"></div>
    <div id="tab-2-content" class="tab-content-item"></div>
    <div id="tab-3-content" class="tab-content-item"></div>
</div>
```